# 'OR' Is Not Working When Checking If Something 'IS NOT' Or '!=' In a String?

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean, conditional-statements

Looked around for an answer, but couldn't find anything. Here's my code:

```
def translate(string, c = 0):
  for char in string:
    if char != 'u' or char != 'i':
        print string[c]
    c += 1

translate("this is fun")
```

If I try this, the whole `if` statement gets canceled out and it returns "t h i s i s f u n" vertically. But, if I do this `if` statement instead, it works perfectly. It only cancels the if statement if I have 2 or more conditions that are =!. Heres 2 if statements that work the way they are supposed to:

```
def translate(string, c = 0):
  for char in string:
    if char == 'u' or char == 'i':
        print string[c]
    c += 1

translate("this is fun")
```

And:

```
def translate(string, c = 0):
  for char in string:
    if char != 'u':
        print string[c]
    c += 1

translate("this is fun")
```

So, does `OR` only work with `==` and not `!=`? I have also tried putting it in English with `is not`.

Comment: Your logic is wrong.  `char != 'u' or char != 'i'` is _always_ true for any value of `char`.  You probably should be using `and`.

Comment: The English phrase "If char is not 'u' or 'i' then..." translates to `if char != 'u' and char != 'i'` (note the `and`) in code. It's because the or is between the alternatives, not between the test conditions. Just one of those things.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, thanks for the answer. You pretty much just summed up poke's post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if char != 'u' or char != 'i':
```

There are three possible cases for this condition:

1. `char` is neither `'u'` nor `'i'`: The condition is obviously true.
2. `char` equals to `'u'`: Now, the first part of the condition is false, but the second is true, since `'u' != 'i'`. So `false or true` yields `true`.
3. `char` equals to `'i'`: Same as before just reversed; `true or false` also yields `true`.

So the problem is that since `char` cannot be two different characters at the same time, one part of your condition is always true. And since you are combining both parts with `or`, one `true` is enough to decide on the result of the whole condition; so the condition always yields true.

To fix this, use `and` since you are now requiring that `char` is not equal to `'u'` but *also* not equal to `'i'`:

```
if char != 'u' and char != 'i':
```

Btw. this is the inverse of your working `char == 'u' or char == 'i'`. This is because of [De Morgan’s laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Comment: Thanks, and I know that the `==` is the inverse, I just noticed that that was something that was working while I was trying to debug. Again, thank you!

Comment: My point was less on `==` being the inverse, but that `a != b and a != c` is the inverse of `a == b or a == c` (`and` instead of `or`).